# how to get data from factories to services in restapi

Tags: angularjs

Here coupon is the my ng-model passing parameter from controllers. i getting the response data. i dont know how to get the this response from factory to services.

please help me..

```
 var factmodule=angular.module("FactModule",["ngResource"]);
factmodule.factory("CouponFactory",function($resource){

   var couponinfo;
   var coupondata
   return{
    getcoupon:function(coupon){

         var user=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/promocode?code="+coupon.offer);
      user.get(function(data){

          couponvalue=data
          console.log(data);
          return couponvalue;

      })


  }        
 }
 })
```

Services code

```
var servctrl=angular.module("ServModule",["FactModule"]);  
servctrl.service("CouponService",function(CouponFactory){

this.checkdata=function(coupon){
   CouponFactory.getcoupon(coupon)
}
 })
```

controllers code

```
// getting coupon code from ng-model in the text box   
mainCtrl.controller("OrderController",function($scope,CouponService){
$scope.validate=function($scope.coupon){ 
CouponService.checkdata($scope.coupon)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If factmodule is in a separate module from servctrl then you need to inject the factmodule into the servctrl on creation of the angular module

e.g.

```js
var servctl = angular.module('servctl', [       
        'factmodule']);
})();
```

what I would be doing is 
app.factory("CouponFactory",function($resource){...
and 
app.service("CouponService",function(CouponFactory){

Then they are in the same module and would be reachable

Comment: i am already inject factmodule in services. here probelm is not the injection. getting the coupon value from factorys.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)</sup>

Since the `return couponvalue;` statement occurs in a function that the `$q` service invokes **in the future**, the factory function which executes **immediately** does not return any data.

Instead return the empty user reference and use its `$promise` property to retrieve the data.

```
var factmodule=angular.module("FactModule",["ngResource"]);

factmodule.factory("CouponFactory",function($resource){

    var couponinfo;
    var coupondata
    return {
      getcoupon:function(coupon){

          var user=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/promocode?code="+coupon.offer);

          //return object reference
          return user.get();
       }        
     }
})
```

Use `$promise` property to retrieve data from the `$q` service.

```
var servctrl=angular.module("ServModule",["FactModule"]);

servctrl.service("CouponService",function(CouponFactory){

    this.checkdata=function(coupon){
        return resourceObject = CouponFactory.getcoupon(coupon);
        //retrieve future data
        resourceObject.$promise.then( onFullfilled(data) {
            var couponvalue=data;
            console.log(data);                
        });
    });
});
```

The `.then` method of a promise takes a function as an argument. The `$q` service stores that function and invokes it **in the future** when the XHR completes.